# Generate all possible 4 digit numbers in PHP and concatenate them with a string

Tags: php

So, I want to generate all possible 4 digit numbers in columns, one by one, (0-9) from 0000 to 9999, and concatenate a string before them, like:

```
text0000
text0001
text0002
text0003
text0004
text0005
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want a line break between each text00... ?

Comment: So what are you expecting from us ? What is your question.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following will do the trick.

```
for($i=0;$i<10000;$i++)
  echo "text".str_pad ($i,4,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT)."<br />";
```

Comment: thanks, this solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
$yourString = 'text';
$generateNumberUpTo=9999;

for ($i = 0; $i <= $generateNumberUpTo; $i++)
    echo sprintf("$yourString%'.04d<br/>", $i);
```